# HTML split on a given character

Tags: python, html, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so I am using beautiful soup to read the html of a page.

```
req = urllib.request.Request('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama', headers = headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(reqx)
page = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
```

I want to split the html code on period on the condition that it does not split when the period is inside another tag other than p tag. 
For instance, if the html code is:

```
<p>In June 2015, the Court ruled 6–3 in <i><a href="/wiki/King_v._Burwell" 
title="King v. Burwell">King v. Burwell</a></i> that subsidies to help individuals 
and families purchase health insurance were authorized for those doing so on both 
the federal exchange and state exchanges, not only those purchasing plans 
"established by the State", as the statute reads.</p>
```

I don't mind splitting on periods in the p tag but not on the ones inside the a tag or any other tag. Converting the html code to string and then splitting obviously would not work. The main reason I don't want to use Beautiful Soup's get_text() method and then split on that is because I want the split to take place on the raw html. Does beautiful soup have a built in split feature wherein I can check if it is splitting on the correct tag? Or is there any other way to do this? Thanks in advance :)

Therefore the output I need is the code split in 2:

```
<p>In June 2015, the Court ruled 6–3 in <i><a href="/wiki/King_v._Burwell" 
title="King v. Burwell">King v


 . Burwell</a></i> that subsidies to help individuals and families purchase health insurance were authorized for those doing so on both the federal exchange and state exchanges, not only those purchasing plans "established by the State", as the statute reads.</p>
```

Comment: So, what is the expected output of splitting the sample code your way?

Comment: Hey, I have edited the question to add the output.